# Mysql on the command line (can't use all keyboard buttons)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-9.10

Using mysql directly from the command line (running on Ubuntu 9.10, standard bash terminal), I am unable to use certain keyboard buttons like:

`Delete, Control-(arrow right), Control-(arrow left)`

Which gets returned to me as:

`~;5C;5D`

respectively. I'm assuming there must be a flag in mysql that fixes this but I have been unable to find one. Is there a .mysqlconfig file to edit to make this happen on startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1147183) and `mysql --version`, mysql is compiled with editline instead of readline. From that thread:

> I had to add create an .editrc file with the following lines to get ctrl-R and DELETE to work.

```
bind "\e[3~" ed-delete-next-char 
bind "^R" em-inc-search-prev
```

Although that didn't work for me.

Another suggestion from that thread did work:

```
$ sudo apt-get install rlwrap
```

Then add an alias in `~/.bashrc`

```
alias mysql='rlwrap -a mysql'
```

This problem may be specific to Ubuntu 9.10

Comment: The last post on the thread worked for me! (accepted for the find) Reproducing the code used here:

$ sudo apt-get install rlwrap
$ alias mysql='rlwrap -a mysql

So basically it seems you are wrapping another program around mysql to get back the vi-like bindings. From the other comments on the thread it seems like this is a bug with Karmic itself.

Comment: This solution seems to handle other terminal-like issues (it worked for Mathematica and MAPLE as well).